# Adding automatic line breaks and hyperlinks to textarea field?

Tags: php

I have a Joomla site that is using some simple php to submit a form, but I like to be able to have it automatically add the line breaks whenever I press enter when entering my text, as well as automatically turning any web address into a clickable link. Is this possible, and can anyone show me how please?

```
    <?php
# FileName="Connection_php_mysql.htm"
# Type="MYSQL"
# HTTP="true"
$hostname_spectac = "localhost";
$database_spectac = "database";
$username_spectac = "username";
$password_spectac = "password";
$spectac = mysql_pconnect($hostname_spectac, $username_spectac, $password_spectac) or trigger_error(mysql_error(),E_USER_ERROR); 
?>
<?php
if(isset($_POST['eventDate'])){
$date = date('Y-m-d',strtotime($_POST['eventDate']));
}
if (!function_exists("GetSQLValueString")) {
function GetSQLValueString($theValue, $theType, $theDefinedValue = "", $theNotDefinedValue = "") 
{
  if (PHP_VERSION < 6) {
    $theValue = get_magic_quotes_gpc() ? stripslashes($theValue) : $theValue;
  }

  $theValue = function_exists("mysql_real_escape_string") ? mysql_real_escape_string($theValue) : mysql_escape_string($theValue);

  switch ($theType) {
    case "text":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . $theValue . "'" : "NULL";
      break;    
    case "long":
    case "int":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? intval($theValue) : "NULL";
      break;
    case "double":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? doubleval($theValue) : "NULL";
      break;
    case "date":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . $theValue . "'" : "NULL";
      break;
    case "defined":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? $theDefinedValue : $theNotDefinedValue;
      break;
  }
  return $theValue;
}
}

$editFormAction = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
if (isset($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])) {
  $editFormAction .= "?" . htmlentities($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);
}

if ((isset($_POST["MM_update"])) && ($_POST["MM_update"] == "form1")) {
  $updateSQL = sprintf("UPDATE tblEventCustom SET eventDate=%s, eventFile=%s, eventActive=%s, eventCost=%s, eventName=%s, eventFriendlyName=%s, eventDesc=%s WHERE eventId=%s",
                       GetSQLValueString($date, "date"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['eventFile'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['eventActive'], "int"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['eventCost'], "int"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['eventName'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['eventFriendlyName'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['eventDesc'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['eventId'], "int"));

  mysql_select_db($database_spectac, $spectac);
  $Result1 = mysql_query($updateSQL, $spectac) or die(mysql_error());
}

$colname_getEventDetails = "-1";
if (isset($_POST['eventId'])) {
  $colname_getEventDetails = $_POST['eventId'];
}
mysql_select_db($database_spectac, $spectac);
$query_getEventDetails = sprintf("SELECT * FROM tblEventCustom WHERE eventId = %s", GetSQLValueString($colname_getEventDetails, "int"));
$getEventDetails = mysql_query($query_getEventDetails, $spectac) or die(mysql_error());
$row_getEventDetails = mysql_fetch_assoc($getEventDetails);
$totalRows_getEventDetails = mysql_num_rows($getEventDetails);

mysql_select_db($database_spectac, $spectac);
$query_getFileList = "SELECT * FROM tbl_eventFiles";
$getFileList = mysql_query($query_getFileList, $spectac) or die(mysql_error());
$row_getFileList = mysql_fetch_assoc($getFileList);
$totalRows_getFileList = mysql_num_rows($getFileList);


?>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
</script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css" />
    <script>
    $(function() {
        $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
        $(eventDate).datepicker({dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'})
    });
    </script>
    <? if ((isset($_POST["MM_update"])) && ($_POST["MM_update"] == "form1")) { ?><div align="center" >Event Updated <br>
      <a href="http://spectaculareventcenter.com/2012/index.php/component/content/article/2-uncategorised/22-editevents">Go back to event list. </a></div><? } ?>
<form method="post" name="form1" action="<?php echo $editFormAction; ?>">
  <table align="center">
    <tr valign="baseline">
      <td nowrap align="right">ID:</td>
      <td><?php echo $row_getEventDetails['eventId']; ?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr valign="baseline">
      <td nowrap align="right">Event Date:</td>
      <td><input type="text" name="eventDate" value="<?php echo htmlentities($row_getEventDetails['eventDate'], ENT_COMPAT, ''); ?>" size="32" id="datepicker"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr valign="baseline">
      <td nowrap align="right">Event Active:</td>
      <td><p>
        <label>
          <input <?php if (!(strcmp($row_getEventDetails['eventActive'],"1"))) {echo "checked=\"checked\"";} ?> type="radio" name="eventActive" value="1" id="RadioGroup1_0">
          Yes</label>
        <br>
        <label>
          <input <?php if (!(strcmp($row_getEventDetails['eventActive'],"0"))) {echo "checked=\"checked\"";} ?> type="radio" name="eventActive" value="0" id="RadioGroup1_1">
          No</label>
        <br>

      </p></td>
    </tr>
    <tr valign="baseline">
      <td nowrap align="right">Event Cost:</td>
      <td><input type="text" name="eventCost" value="<?php echo htmlentities($row_getEventDetails['eventCost'], ENT_COMPAT, ''); ?>" size="32"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr valign="baseline">
      <td nowrap align="right">Event Name:</td>
      <td><input type="text" name="eventName" value="<?php echo htmlentities($row_getEventDetails['eventName'], ENT_COMPAT, ''); ?>" size="32"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr valign="baseline">
      <td nowrap align="right">Display Name:</td>
      <td><input type="text" name="eventFriendlyName" value="<?php echo htmlentities($row_getEventDetails['eventFriendlyName'], ENT_COMPAT, ''); ?>" size="32"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr valign="baseline">
      <td nowrap align="right">Event Desc:</td>
      <td><textarea cols=32 rows=5 name="eventDesc" value="<?php echo htmlentities($row_getEventDetails['eventDesc'], ENT_COMPAT, ''); ?>" size="32"></textarea></td>
    </tr>
    <tr valign="baseline">
      <td nowrap align="right">Event File:</td>
      <td><select name="eventFile">
        <?php
do {  
?>
        <option value="<?php echo $row_getFileList['fileName']?>"<?php if (!(strcmp($row_getFileList['fileName'], $row_getEventDetails['eventFile']))) {echo "selected=\"selected\"";} ?>><?php echo $row_getFileList['fileName']?></option>
        <?php
} while ($row_getFileList = mysql_fetch_assoc($getFileList));
  $rows = mysql_num_rows($getFileList);
  if($rows > 0) {
      mysql_data_seek($getFileList, 0);
      $row_getFileList = mysql_fetch_assoc($getFileList);
  }
?>
      </select>
      <a href="http://spectaculareventcenter.com/2012/customCode/file_upload.php" target="_blank">Upload File</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr valign="baseline">
      <td nowrap align="right">&nbsp;</td>
      <td><input type="submit" value="Update record"></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <p>
    <input type="hidden" name="MM_update" value="form1">
    <input type="hidden" name="eventId" value="<?php echo $row_getEventDetails['eventId']; ?>">
  </p>
</form>

<?php
mysql_free_result($getEventDetails);

mysql_free_result($getFileList);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [nl2br](http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php) on the input string before storing it into the database. As for automatic links, explode the input string by whitespace, loop over all the words (or use array_walk()) and call

```
filter_var($yourstring, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL);
```

on it. If it returns true then simply add html link tags around it and replace the array element. Finally, implode your array to get the cleartext for storing in database.

[Here is a function for adding link I found with quick google search.](http://krasimirtsonev.com/blog/article/php--find-links-in-a-string-and-replace-them-with-actual-html-link-tags)

As for your third comment, if you want to be able to edit the original text that was in the textarea I suggest you do not use nl2br before inserting it into database. Instead, save original text and only use nl2br when displaying the data to the page, so.. whenever you echo it.

Comment: How do I add the nl2br on the input string? can you tell me what line and how i do it? i think you just put nl2br before this isn't it? GetSQLValueString($_POST['eventDesc'], "text") like before the $_POST part is that right?

Comment: Okay, I got the line breaks to work for me, but I have no clue what you just said about the links. Can you please re-explain it slowly and very detailed? I'm a complete idiot when it comes to doing this and it takes time for me to learn some things, like this one :-(

Comment: One other question: when I go back to try to edit it, what I previously entered into the textarea field doesn't show (all the other fields do though!). How can I make the textarea field data show, too?